# Get all images from the database and display the images in a bootstrap 4 carousel Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I've been trying to get all the images from the database and trying to display them in a bootstrap carousel but it is only returning one image.

```
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            @if($posts->active == 1)
                            <img  src="{{ Storage::url("image/{$posts->image}") }}" alt="..." class="d-block img-fluid">
                            @endif
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h3 class="text-white">{{ $posts->title }}</h3>
                                <p>{{ $posts->h1 }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And here is the code in the controller index function

```
$posts = Post::latest()->first();
```

When I try to change the method to get() instead of first() an error appears. I'm not sure if I need to setup a new variable for the images, or include a foreach in the view which I'm not sure how to do. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: how are the image stored in the database? and try to figure out difference between `get()` method and `first()` method of [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent). Read the docs it will help you to understand some more

Comment: I know `first()` returns the first result from the array and `get()` returns all the results, but using that method produces an error that all the properties don't exist on this collection instance. However I have used `dd();` to test and it's outputting the right data. As for how the images are stored is through the store function in the posts controller that does a request to see if a file has been uploaded.

Comment: first() returns the model class you are fetching of. And `get()` will give you the Eloquent Collection object so you will have to loop through it using foreach eg: `foreach($posts as $post)` so you can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @if($post->active == 1)
        <img src="{{ Storage::url("image/{$post->image}") }}" alt="..." class="d-block img-fluid">
    @endif
    <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h3 class="text-white">{{ $post->title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ $post->h1 }}</p>
    </div>
@endforeach

</div>
```

You can access your posts like this if you are using `get()` method. 
Since `first()` method directly returns you the model you can access its properties but for `get()` you will have to loop through it since it returns "Eloquent Collection' (not array, you can use [toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays) if you need one).

Comment: Tried using the `get()` method in my controller and then did a foreach in the view. It is saying the properties don't exist. For example ;
`Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance` but for all the properties using the $post variable.

Comment: Fixed it I defined the wrong variable and all the images are showing now thank you very much.